# Does Firestore listener only transfer changed data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener, billing

I would like to now what amount of data is send and billed with a Firestore document listener.

1. Does the listener only sends changes to client or all the document ?
2. What is the bill if I listen a 100Kb document and it changes of 1Kb ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore always transfers the entire document if any of it has changed.  There are no partial document downloads.  If this is going to be problematic, you can split the fields that are going to change frequently into separate documents, in order to minimize the amount of time and bandwidth it will take for the client to receive the changes.